# Sum of length between nodes in a vector

Tags: c++

I have the following Task: I am doing an implementation of the Cheapest Insertion method and I am storing my subtours into a `vector`. After building the `vector`, I Need to find the total length of the distances between the nodes, that are included in the `vector` (for example I have `0-32-41-3-45-0` stored in the `vector`). How can I calculate the total distance? I have the following function:

```
double tLength = 0;
for (vector<int>::iterator i=resultingRoute.begin(); i!=resultingRoute.end();i++)
{

    tLength+= distanceMatrix[*i][*i+1];
}
return tLength;
```

but it is calculating from 0 to 1, then from 32 to 33, 41 to 42, and so on. What I Need is 0 to 32, 32 to 41, 41 to 3. I tried to create a second iterator `j` to start `at.begin()+1`, but it is repeating the second part of the function too much.

```
double tLength = 0;
for (vector<int>::iterator i=resultingRoute.begin(); i!=resultingRoute.end()-1;i++)
{
    for(vector<int>::iterator j=resultingRoute.begin()+1;j!=resultingRoute.end();j++)
    {
    tLength+= distanceMatrix[*i][*j];
    }
}
return tLength;
```

What is the best way to calculate the length of the tour? Thanks.

Comment: `resultingRoute.begin()+1`/`resultingRoute.end()-1` This is dangerous, at least for an empty vector.

Answer (score 1):

> but it is calculating from 0 to 1, then from 32 to 33, 41 to 42, and
>   so on

It indeed does it as the `*i+1` takes value of `*i` and adds a `1` to it. You probably wanted to write `*(i+1)`. In that case the condition `i!=resultingRoute.end()` is incorrect, it should be `i!=resultingRoute.end()-1`, otherwise the `*(i+1)` would be out of range for last element. You should also check whether the vector has at least 2 elements before entering the loop.

You can avoid the iterators and work with the vector as if it were an array, without the need to check the vector's size:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < resultingRoute.size(); ++i)
        tLength += distanceMatrix[resultingRoute[i]][resultingRoute[i+1]];
```